# method giving app crashes due to segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, crash, segmentation-fault

this simple loop method is unable to run and an error arises **"app crashed"**. when i checked this in an online compiler it gave **'segmentation fault(core dumped)'**-

```
string studies(setMatter ch) {
  string a = "LISTEN CAREFULLY!\n";
  int i = 0;
  while (i <= ch.a.quantity()) {
    a += ch.a.getAns(i);
    i++;
  }
  return a;
}
```

also see for reference of methods in the above code-

```
class Answer {
 private:
  vector<string> ch;

 public:
  void setAns(string ans) { ch.push_back(ans); }

  string getAns(int num) { return (ch[num]); }

  int quantity() { return ch.size(); }
};
```

am i accessing elements out of bond? but i dont know where as i every number starts from 0 in programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are.

```
while(i<=ch.a.quantity()){
```

should be

```
while(i<ch.a.quantity()){
```

Valid vector indexes are zero up to the size of the vector minus one. That should be obvious, if the valid indexes started at zero and went to the size of the vector then there would be one more valid index than the size of the vector, which makes no sense.

Generally you use a for loop for this kind of task

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.a.quantity(); i++) {
    a += ch.a.getAns(i);
}
```

It's a little easier to read that way.

Comment: Thank you, but the app crash still exists when this method is called. On printing the value of a , "listen carefully" got printed but after that the app crashed. Please help me.thanks in advance!!

Comment: @hemantkumar The function above doesn't print anything. So your crash is probably in a different function. What makes you think that it is in this function?

Comment: But the above function returns the value of a, and starting lines are "listen carefully".I have printed a simply using cout<<

Comment: @hemantkumar I'm sorry, but how am I supposed to know about code you haven't previously mentioned. In any case the crash might still be after this function has returned. If I understand correctly then this function cannot be causing a crash, now that you have fixed the `<=` issue. But since I cannot see your latest code I might be wrong.